# $(document).ready does not fire on removing a section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was looking at this template html file (below). When I comment out the div from lines 168 to 195 the Nav bar stops becoming sticky. On spending more than an hour on this I see that when I comment that section the $(document).ready function does not trigger anymore. All net search just says that probably jquery was not included properly but the file seems to be getting called since when I start I can trigger the breakpoint at the beginning of the jquery file.
     Any help to figure out why this would be happening would be really helpful. The whole file structure is at [this location](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6Zj_ZMylrarMW9FU29Dc01QdFU)

The file is:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>    <html class="no-js ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--> <html> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Flatfy Free Flat and Responsive HTML5 Template ">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Flatfy – Free Flat and Responsive HTML5 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Google Web Font -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Custom CSS-->
    <link href="css/general.css" rel="stylesheet">

     <!-- Owl-Carousel -->
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Magnific Popup core CSS file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css"> 

    <script src="js/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>  <!-- Modernizr /-->
    <!--[if IE 9]>
        <script src="js/PIE_IE9.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="js/PIE_IE678.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body id="home">

    <!-- Preloader -->
    <div id="preloader">
        <div id="status"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- FullScreen -->
    <div class="intro-header">
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center abcen1">
            <h1 class="h1_home wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.4s">Flatfy</h1>
            <h3 class="h3_home wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.6s">Clean & minimal Theme</h3>
            <ul class="list-inline intro-social-buttons">
                <li><a href="https://twitter.com/galantiandrea" class="btn  btn-lg mybutton_cyano wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.8s"><span class="network-name">Twitter</span></a>
                </li>
                <li id="download" ><a href="#downloadlink" class="btn  btn-lg mybutton_standard wow swing wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="1.2s"><span class="network-name">Free Download</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>    
        <!-- /.container -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center abcen wow fadeIn">
            <div class="button_down "> 
                <a class="imgcircle wow bounceInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s"  href="#whatis"> <img class="img_scroll" src="img/icon/circle.png" alt=""> </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- NavBar-->
    <nav class="navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Flatfy</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li class="menuItem"><a href="#whatis">What is?</a></li>
                    <li class="menuItem"><a href="#useit">Use It</a></li>
                    <li class="menuItem"><a href="#screen">Screenshot</a></li>
                    <li class="menuItem"><a href="#credits">Credits</a></li>
                    <li class="menuItem"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </nav> 

    <!-- What is -->
    <div id="whatis" class="content-section-b" style="border-top: 0">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center wrap_title">
                <h2>What is?</h2>
                <p class="lead" style="margin-top:0">A special thanks to Death.</p>

            </div>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-4 wow fadeInDown text-center">
                  <img class="rotate" src="img/icon/tweet.svg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                  <h3>Follow Me</h3>
                  <p class="lead">Epsum factorial non deposit quid pro quo hic escorol. Olypian quarrels et gorilla congolium sic ad nauseum. </p>

                  <!-- <p><a class="btn btn-embossed btn-primary view" role="button">View Details</a></p> -->
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->

                <div class="col-sm-4 wow fadeInDown text-center">
                  <img  class="rotate" src="img/icon/picture.svg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                   <h3>Gallery</h3>
                   <p class="lead">Epsum factorial non deposit quid pro quo hic escorol. Olypian quarrels et gorilla congolium sic ad nauseum. </p>
                   <!-- <p><a class="btn btn-embossed btn-primary view" role="button">View Details</a></p> -->
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->

                <div class="col-sm-4 wow fadeInDown text-center">
                  <img  class="rotate" src="img/icon/retina.svg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                   <h3>Retina</h3>
                    <p class="lead">Epsum factorial non deposit quid pro quo hic escorol. Olypian quarrels et gorilla congolium sic ad nauseum. </p>
                  <!-- <p><a class="btn btn-embossed btn-primary view" role="button">View Details</a></p> -->
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->

            </div><!-- /.row -->

            <div class="row tworow">

                <div class="col-sm-4  wow fadeInDown text-center">
                  <img class="rotate" src="img/icon/laptop.svg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                  <h3>Responsive</h3>
                  <p class="lead">Epsum factorial non deposit quid pro quo hic escorol. Olypian quarrels et gorilla congolium sic ad nauseum. </p>
                 <!-- <p><a class="btn btn-embossed btn-primary view" role="button">View Details</a></p> -->
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->

                <div class="col-sm-4 wow fadeInDown text-center">
                  <img  class="rotate" src="img/icon/map.svg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                   <h3>Google</h3>
                   <p class="lead">Epsum factorial non deposit quid pro quo hic escorol. Olypian quarrels et gorilla congolium sic ad nauseum. </p>
                   <!-- <p><a class="btn btn-embossed btn-primary view" role="button">View Details</a></p> -->
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->

                <div class="col-sm-4 wow fadeInDown text-center">
                  <img  class="rotate" src="img/icon/browser.svg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                   <h3>Bootstrap</h3>
                 <p class="lead">Epsum factorial non deposit quid pro quo hic escorol. Olypian quarrels et gorilla congolium sic ad nauseum. </p>
                  <!-- <p><a class="btn btn-embossed btn-primary view" role="button">View Details</a></p> -->
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->

            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div  class="content-section-c ">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center white">
                <h2>Get Live Updates</h2>
                <p class="lead" style="margin-top:0">A special thanks to Death.</p>
             </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
                <div class="mockup-content">
                        <div class="morph-button wow pulse morph-button-inflow morph-button-inflow-1">
                            <button type="button "><span>Subscribe to our Newsletter</span></button>
                            <div class="morph-content">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="content-style-form content-style-form-4 ">
                                        <h2 class="morph-clone">Subscribe to our Newsletter</h2>
                                        <form>
                                            <p><label>Your Email Address</label><input type="text"/></p>
                                            <p><button>Subscribe me</button></p>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  





    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <!-- StikyMenu -->
    <script src="js/stickUp.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(function($) {
        $(document).ready( function() {
          $('.navbar-default').stickUp();

        });
      });

    </script>
    <!-- Smoothscroll -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.corner.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     new WOW().init();
    </script>
    <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
    <script src="js/uiMorphingButton_inflow.js"></script>
    <!-- Magnific Popup core JS file -->
    <script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Rule 318 starts a div which isn't closed if you comment out rule 319 to 346.

Comment: @godblessstrawberry  Using jquery it will still fire again though, if document.ready has already fired, calling again will just return immediate.  Saying this, having document.ready, waiting for document.ready doesn't really make sense, just doing `$(function () {` would suffice.

Comment: The navbar isn't removed through jQuery but actually just commented out.

Comment: I snipped the HTML file. Now it is a smaller file. I still have the same problem. If I snip of the div element starting at line 168 all the way to line 195 then the $(document).ready is not triggered any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what was going wrong. Because I removed all morphing elements from the file the uiMorphingButton_inflow.js was throwing this error and preventing other events from happening. Once I removed the reference to this file. It works fine!